# What is the proper use of several \seealso in the same index entry with makeindex?

Tags: indexing, warnings

If one uses

```
\index{invariant!\relax|seealso{Lorentz invariance}}%
\index{invariant!\relax|seealso{speed of light}}%
```

in a `.tex` file, the makeindex program produces a warning in the `.ilg` file, when it processes the second entry:

```
## Warning (input = motionmountain-volume4.idx, line = 29; output = motionmountain-volume4.ind, line = 618):
   -- Conflicting entries: multiple encaps for the same page under same key.
```

What is the proper way to have several `\seealso` under one entry, without generating any warnings?

Clarification: the result at present is that despite the warnings all the entries get added, in a series that looks like *seealso* entry1 *seealso* entry2 etc.

In my dream, the wanted result is that every *seealso* starts its own subentry, and that no warnings appear.

Comment: since `\seealso` omits the page number, the best approach i've found so far is to combine the entries: `\index{invariant!\gobbble |seealso{Lorentz invariance; speed of light}}` with `\providecommand{\gobble}[1]{}`.  this gets rid of the leading comma, but leaves a leading space.  (been working on this for a long time, but have yet to find a satisfying solution.)

Comment: A provocative proposal: Could one not take the warning out?

Comment: i'm not really prepared to undertake modification of `makeindex`, but am trying to find an approach that can produce acceptable output with the possible necessity of redefining some macros.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the following test file produces *see also* references from entries where multiple
targets are combined in a single input.  since `\seealso` omits page numbers, i don't
see any reason not to combine the targets.  (just don't forget to enclose them in
braces, so that `\seealso` sees them as a single argument.)

this coding will set the *see also* text as the last second-level entry for the
main item.  `\igobble` removes the leading comma and space.  it should be trivial
to create a simple two-argument command to insert the "extra" coding.

this method produces no warnings, a problem noted in the original question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\def\igobble#1 {}

\begin{document}

some text\index{a} with some index entries\index{b}
and some\index{c} \emph{see also} entries as well.
\index{a!zzzzz@\igobble |seealso {b, c}}
\index{a!bcd}
\index{c!zzzzz@\igobble |seealso {a, b}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

thanks to andrew swann for the suggestion to use a plain-style definition that will
solve the problem of removing an unwanted space.  (my latex friends have been trying
to break me of the habit of using plain-style commands.  but in some situations,
latex(2e) has no satisfactory approach.)

**edit:**
the op would prefer to have each *see also* entry on a separate line.  this can be done,
but requires additional attention, mostly bookkeeping.  if the dummy sort field is the
same for all *see also* entries for one main entry, warnings are unavoidable, although
the output would be okay.  to avoid the warnings, different dummy sort fields can be
applied.  if doing this, it's necessary to assign them so that the desired final order
will be achieved; this is easy enough if all the `\seealso` entries are located together
in the input file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\def\igobble#1 {}

\begin{document}

some text\index{a} with some index entries\index{b}
and some\index{c} \emph{see also} entries as well.
\index{a!zzzza@\igobble |seealso {b}}
\index{a!zzzzb@\igobble |seealso {c}}
\index{a!bcd}
\index{c!zzzza@\igobble |seealso {a}}
\index{c!zzzzb@\igobble |seealso {b}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

the choice of the dummy sort field will govern where in the index the entry will be
placed.  in this example, `zzzzx` (with `x` variable) was used to force them
to the end.  if, instead, they are preferred at the beginning, something like
`0 00x` can be used, since digits sort before letters, and the likelihood of
actual second-level index entries beginning "zero space" is vanishingly small.

Comment: The issue I have here I that sometimes the entry after \seealso has a comma. Ideally, I would like to have two separate lines, each one starting with \seealso.

Comment: You can remove the space too by using `\igobble` defined by `\def\igobble#1 {}`

Comment: @AndrewSwann -- brilliant!  thanks!  (this goes into my in-progress tome on indexing.  as well as an update here.)

Comment: Thank you for all the details. By the way, the trick works well without \igooble for me (with \igobble it takes out the whole entry). (I use texlive on OSX.) Maybe we should add and explanation, for future ereference, on what to do when we want the seealsos to appear at the beginning of the entry list, instead of at the end.

Comment: @MotionMountain -- good suggestion about the initial sort, thanks.  added.  i'm not sure why you don't need `\igobble`; with the default setup and no special instructions to `makeindex`, the comma is inserted by `makeindex` itself, not defined in a `.cls` or `.sty` file.  so that's the reason for needing to get rid of it.  but your comment should serve as fair warning to users of non-default setups.