# Multiple \seealso under one index entry with imakeidx and texindy

Tags: errors, indexing, imakeidx, xindy

I need to have several `seealso` under one index entry. I tried several ways to get this work. First variant (see below) produces semicolons between entries but I need commas as separators. Other variants produces good output but throws the errors like `ERROR: Cross-reference-target ("a, c") does not exist!`. There is the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231899/87293) with `makeidx` but I need to solve it with `imakedx` and `xindy`.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-M texindy]

\begin{document}
foo\index{a} \index{b} \index{c} \index{d}

\index{a|seealso{c}} \index{a|seealso{d}} %1st

\index{b|seealso{a, c}} %2nd

\index{c\relax |seealso{a, b}} %3rd

\index{d\gobble |seealso{b, c}} %4th

\printindex
\end{document}
```

My output:

[image: multiple see also]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The separator for multiple `seealso` entries is defined in the file `makeindex.xdy`, which is normally located in the `xindy` installation directory. If you create an alternative `makeindex.xdy` file in the directory where your `.tex` file is stored then the alternative file is loaded. For example the following, which outputs a comma without errors for the first variant:

`makeindex.xdy`

```
(define-crossref-class "see")
(markup-crossref-list :class "see" :open "\see{" :sep ", " :close "}{}")

(define-crossref-class "seealso")
(markup-crossref-list :class "seealso" :open "\seealso{" :sep ", " :close "}{}")

(markup-crossref-layer-list :sep ", ")

(define-location-class-order ("roman-page-numbers"
                  "arabic-page-numbers"
                  "alpha-page-numbers"
                  "Roman-page-numbers"
                  "Alpha-page-numbers"
                  "see"
                  "seealso"))
```

Result:

[image]

It may also be possible to set the alternative rule as a command line option, however I didn't find a way to do that.

Comment: Thank a lot. I have an additional question however. Your example work well as long as xindy style file is named `makeindex.xdy`. If I have another filename and call it by `\makeindex[program=truexindy,options=-M texindy -M another_filename.xdy]` output result is the same but now I have some errors: `ERROR: replacing location-reference-class `"see"' is not allowed !` and `ERROR: replacing location-reference-class `"seealso"' is not allowed !`. It is not essentially to have style file with another filename just wondering what is the reason of such routine.

Comment: When you use another filename the original file `makeindex.xdy` is also loaded, I'm guessing the `\makeindex` command loads a file with this name by default and additionally any other files that are passed in the options. Therefore the rules for `see` and `seealso` are loaded first from `makeindex.xdy` and then you try to load new definitions for the same commands from your custom file, which is not allowed. Defining a new command in another file is allowed, i.e., `\index{a|myseealso{c}}` and `(define-crossref-class "myseealso")
(markup-crossref-list :class "myseealso" :open "\seealso{"` etc.

Comment: Commenting out lines `(define-crossref-class "see")` and `(define-crossref-class "seealso")` solves this "problem".