# Change index "see also" and "see" format

Tags: indexing

## Desired index result

I want an index using `makeindex`to have entries like the following (where I've used ~~~ and ~~~~~~ to indicate indenting for subentries and sub subentries):

> nothing, 1
>    ~~~ nil, 1
>    ~~~~~~ and zero, 1
>    ~~~~~~ (*see also* null elements}
>    ~~~ null, 1
>    ~~~ *See also* zero elements
>      null elements, 1
>
> zero (*see* zero elements)
>      zero elements, 1

Note the following formatting requirements shown:

- A "*See also* ..." for a main entry begins with an upper-case "*S*".
- A "(*see also* ...)" for a subentry is indented below the subentry and enclosed in parens.
- A "(*see* ...)" cross-reference is enclosed in parens.
- A "(*see* ...)" cross-reference does *not* include a comma after the (sub)entry on its line.
- A "*see*" or "*see also*"/"*See also*" entry does *not* end with a page number.

Here's a screen shot of the printed index:
[image]

## A working source file that produces the result

The following source file will accomplish that:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\newcommand\gobbleone[1]{}
\newcommand*{\seeonly}[2]{\ (\emph{\seename} #1)}
\newcommand*{\also}[2]{(\emph{\alsoname} #1)}
\newcommand{\Also}[2]{\emph{See also} #1}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

This is a short book about zero. Therefore, it's also about nothing.
Which means null (or nil).

\index{nothing}
\index{nothing!nil}
\index{nothing!nil!and zero}   % added for clarity
\index{nothing!nil!zzzzz@\also{null elements}|gobbleone}
\index{nothing!null}
\index{nothing!zzzzz@\Also{zero elements}|gobbleone}
\index{null elements}

\index{zero \seeonly{zero elements}|gobbleone}
\index{zero elements}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

## Simplification & improvement sought

Can this be simplified by suitable definitions that would avoid having to explicitly include the `|gobbleone` in each "see only" and "see" entry? And it would even be better if I did not have to explicitly include the `zzzzz@` sort key that puts the "see also" subentries after all others.

I would strongly prefer definitions written in LaTeX (using `newcommand`) rather than at lower-level TeX (using `\def`).

These related postings unfortunately do not seem to accomplish what I need:

- [Indexing, subentries, and see also](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86646/indexing-subentries-and-see-also/86910#86910)
- [modified "see" command adds spurious page number](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=21464&hilit=see+also+index&start=10)

Comment: Is this for a type of synonyms dictionary? Can't figure _exactly_ why this would be done ...

Comment: @nilon: no, for an ordinary index. The indicated format is just the desired style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SECOND EDIT

(I don't know what is the usual practice. I have left the initial answer and edit at the bottom and the new one here at the start).

To fullfill all the requirements, instead of manipulating the argument of `\index`, I have made three new commands with two arguments to take care of it.
The first argument is the entry in the index and the second the *see* text.
The commands are:

```
\seeonlyindex{<index entry>}{<see text>} 
\alsoindex{<index entry>}{<see text>} 
\Alsoindex{<index entry>}{<see text>}
```

The result is:

[image]

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\newcommand\gobbleone[1]{}
\newcommand{\seeonly}[2]{\ (\emph{\seename} #1)}
\newcommand{\also}[2]{\unskip(\emph{\alsoname} #1)}
\newcommand{\Also}[2]{\unskip\emph{See also} #1}
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\def\exptoindex{#1}\expandafter\oldindex\expandafter{\exptoindex}}

\newcommand{\seeonlyindex}[2]{\index{#1@#1\protect\gobbleone|seeonly{#2}}}
\newcommand{\alsoindex}[2]{\index{#1!zzzz@\protect\gobbleone|also{#2}}}
\newcommand{\Alsoindex}[2]{\index{#1!zzzz@\protect\gobbleone|Also{#2}}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

This is a short book about zero. Therefore, it's also about nothing.
Which means null (or nil).

\index{nothing}
\index{nothing!nil}
\index{nothing!nil!and zero}
\alsoindex{nothing!nil}{null elements}
\index{nothing!null}
\Alsoindex{nothing}{zero elements}
\index{null elements}

\seeonlyindex{zero}{zero elements}
\index{zero elements}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

OLD SECTION

To avoid the use of `|gobbleone` to get rid of the page numbers, you have to insert the commands the `makeidx` way with `|` and not the `LaTeX` way with `\`.

To have these entries in the last place, you still will need `\gobbleone` to eliminate the comma.

```
\index{nothing!nil!zzzz@\gobbleone|also{null elements}}
```

[image: edited to remove unwanted space]
(edited to remove unwanted space)

An additional command `\lastentry`makes typing easier, but the `\index` command must be renewed and then a `\def` is required to have the content of `\index` expanded.

The complete code:
(edited to remove unwanted space)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\newcommand\gobbleone[1]{}
\newcommand{\seeonly}[2]{\ (\emph{\seename} #1)}
\newcommand{\also}[2]{\unskip(\emph{\alsoname} #1)}
\newcommand{\Also}[2]{\unskip\emph{See also} #1}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

This is a short book about zero. Therefore, it's also about nothing.
Which means null (or nil).


\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\def\exptoindex{#1}\expandafter\oldindex\expandafter{\exptoindex}}
\newcommand{\lastentry}{!zzzz@\protect\gobbleone}

\index{nothing}
\index{nothing!nil}
%\index{nothing!nil!zzzz@\gobbleone|also{null elements}}
\index{nothing!nil\lastentry|also{null elements}}
\index{nothing!null}
%\index{nothing!zzzz@\gobbleone|Also{zero elements}}
\index{nothing\lastentry|Also{zero elements}}
\index{null elements}

\index{zero|seeonly{zero elements}}
\index{zero elements}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Although this is interesting, it has several defects: (1) the entry "zero, (*see* zero elements)" has an unwanted comma; (2) both the "(*see also* ...) and the "*See also* ..." entries are not correctly aligned (each has unwanted additional space at its start). I'm adding one more index entry and including a screen shot in my post to clarify what's needed.

Comment: @murray The additional space is easily removed with `\unskip`. The comma might be more difficult to remove, since it is the default in the `|`construct in `\makeidx`. I edit my reply to remove the additional space.

Comment: Need to get rid of that comma, too!

Comment: @murray: The comma is gone now, but possibly not all thinkable circumstances are covered. In any case, the example now works as you wanted and mainly `\newcommand` has been used.

Comment: I'm still getting a comma in the printed entry from \index{zero|seeonly{zero elements}}

Comment: @murray: No, no. I have changed the whole thing. The new answer and commands are at the beginning. Now you should use `\seeonlyindex{zero}{zero elements}`. The other two forms have also been converted to commands with two arguments. I think that this is easier to use than having to write several commands in the `\index` argument some with `\` and others with `|`.

Comment: Oops, sorry I carelessly copied the wrong code block to try. This seems to work just fine. I'll bang on i to see if any odd situations arise, but definitely it *does* work as advertised.