# Conflict with makeindex using babel and memoir?

Tags: memoir, babel, makeindex

**Revised question** (I've been able to eliminate all extraneous definitions from my original source project and yet still reproduce this error with a MWE.)

On the `memoir` document source below, I've run `pdflatex`, `makeindex` (with the `-s` option for the indicated  `.ist` style file), and then `pdflatex` again. On that final run of `pdflatex` I get the error `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup`. Specifically, the log shows:

```
Redoing nameref's sectioning
Redoing nameref's label
(./indexerr.out) (./indexerr.out) [1{/Users/murray/Library/texlive/2019/texmf-v
ar/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] [3] (./indexerr.ind
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmss.fd) [4] [5]
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...entry@wrap {\@nameuse {indexeheadr}}
                                                  \@nameuse {indexpsheadstru...
l.110 \end{theindex}
```

The error does *not* occur if I omit the `babel` commands from the preamble!

What could the error source be?

```
%% INDEXERR.TEX
\begin{filecontents}{indexerr.ist}
% MakeIndex style file
% output main entry <entry> as: \item \idxmark{<entry>}, 
item_0  "\n\\item \\idxmark{"
delim_0 "}, "
% not forgetting the subitem case
item_x1 "} \n \\subitem "
%%headings_flag 1
%%heading_prefix "{\\textsf{\\textbf{"
%%heading_suffix "}}}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\medskip\\hfill\\large\\textsf{\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\hfill}\\medskip\\nopagebreak\n"
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{memoir}

%% BABEL (actually used with multiple languages)
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\RequirePackage[main=english]{babel}%

%% HEADINGS
\makeheadrule {headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}   
\makepagestyle{index}
\makeheadrule{index}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenhead{index}%
{\sffamily\bfseries\rightmark}%
{\sffamily\bfseries\MakeTextUppercase{\indexname}}%
{\sffamily\bfseries\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{index}%
{\sffamily\bfseries\rightmark}%
{\sffamily\bfseries\MakeTextUppercase{\indexname}}%
{\sffamily\bfseries\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{index}{}{\sffamily\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{index}{}{\sffamily\thepage}{}         

%% INDEXING
\newcommand\gobbleone[1]{}
\newcommand{\seeonly}[2]{\, (\emph{\seename} #1)}
\newcommand{\also}[2]{\unskip(\emph{\alsoname} #1)}
\newcommand{\Also}[2]{\unskip\emph{See also} #1}
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\def\exptoindex{#1}\expandafter\oldindex\expandafter{\exptoindex}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\indexsee}[2]{\index{#1\protect\gobbleone|seeonly{#2}}}
\newcommand{\indexalso}[2]{\index{#1!zzzz@\protect\gobbleone|also{#2}}}
\newcommand{\indexAlso}[2]{\index{#1!zzzz@\protect\gobbleone|Also{#2}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\indexnamesee}[2]{\index[names]{#1\protect\gobbleone|seeonly{#2}}}
% fix for memoir to put hyperlink on mainref, too:
\newcommand{\mainref}[1]{\textbf{\emph{\hyperpage{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\idxmark}[1]{{\let\gobbleone\relax\markboth{\sffamily\bfseries#1}{\sffamily\bfseries#1}}#1}

%% CROSS-REFERENCING
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\mainmatter

\chapter{The chapter}

This is a short book about zero. Therefore, it's also about nothing.
Which means null (or nil).
%
\index{nothing}
\index{nothing!nil}
\index{nothing!nil!and zero}
\index{nothing!null}
\indexalso{nothing!nil}{null elements}
\indexsee{nothing!nada}{nothing!nil}
\indexsee{zero}{zero elements}
\indexAlso{nothing}{zero elements}
\indexsee{thing}{something}
\index{null elements}

\newpage
More.
\index{nothing}
\index{nothing!nil}
\index{nothing!nil!and zero}
\index{null elements}
\index{zero elements}

\newpage
Still more.
\index{closed interval}
\index{continuous function!and bounded function}
\index{cover!and open cover}
\index{open cover|mainref}
\index{open cover|(}

\newpage
Yet more
\index{znothing}
\index{znothing!nil}
\index{znothing!nil!and zero}
\index{znothing!null}
\indexalso{znothing!nil}{null elements}
\indexsee{zzero}{zero elements}
\indexAlso{znothing}{zero elements}
\indexsee{zthing}{something}
\index{znull elements}

Something.
\index{ynothing}
\index{ynothing!nil}
\index{ynothing!nil!and zero}
\index{ynothing!null}
\indexalso{ynothing!nil}{null elements}
\indexsee{yzero}{zero elements}
\indexAlso{ynothing}{zero elements}
\indexsee{ything}{something}
\index{ynull elements}
Really nothing,
\index{xnothing}
\index{xnothing!nil}
\index{nothing!nil!and zero}
\index{xnothing!null}
\indexalso{xnothing!nil}{xnull elements}
\indexsee{xzero}{xzero elements}
\indexAlso{xnothing}{xzero elements}
\indexsee{xthing}{xsomething}
\index{xnull elements}
Getting repetitous!
\index{wnothing}
\index{wnothing!nil}
\index{wnothing!nil!and zero}
\index{wnothing!null}
\indexalso{wnothing!nil}{wnull elements}
\indexsee{wzero}{wzero elements}
\indexAlso{wnothing}{wzero elements}
\indexsee{wthing}{wsomething}
\index{wnull elements}
Still is.
\index{vnothing}
\index{vnothing!nil}
\index{vnothing!nil!and zero}
\index{vnothing!null}
\indexalso{vnothing!nil}{vnull elements}
\indexsee{vzero}{vzero elements}
\indexAlso{vnothing}{vzero elements}
\indexsee{vthing}{vsomething}
\index{vnull elements}

Hope this is enough.
\index{unothing}
\index{unothing!nil}
\index{unothing!nil!and zero}
\index{unothing!null}
\indexalso{unothing!nil}{unull elements}
\indexsee{uzero}{uzero elements}
\indexAlso{unothing}{uzero elements}
\indexsee{uthing}{usomething}
\index{unull elements}

\pagestyle{index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

*Notes:* The definitions of indexing commands `\seeonly,`\also`, etc., and the auxiliary`\gobbleone`come from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318472/change-index-see-also-and-see-format. The definitions of`\indexsee`and`\idxmark` come from [Error with entries in index page header, memoir class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332093/error-with-entries-in-index-page-header-memoir-class/332098#332098).

Comment: search your code for `\@nameuse {indexoheadl}` as that is followed by one extra bracket (it doesn't mean the error is there tex probably got lost earlier but find that and work backwards....

Comment: also it might be `\@nameuse {i#1}`  where `#1`  is `indexoheadl` so you need to be fairly open in your search queries

Comment: I searched *all* files used in my project, including those generated up to and including the point where I get the error. But I don't  find `\@nameuse` at all, anywhere!

Comment: What I find in `.log` is: `./topologybook.ind:1152: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...entry@wrap {\@nameuse {indexeheadr}}
                                                  \@nameuse {indexpsheadstru...
l.1152     \subitem
                    of a relation, \hyperpage{12}`

Comment: grep for `pshead` across the tex input tree suggests it's in memoir `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:  \@namedef{#1psheadstrut}{\@nameuse{#2psheadstrut}}
`

Comment: I didn't look into texlive-distro files. What do I do about this? `memoir.cls` does not seem to have changed since 2018/12/12, and I've certainly successfully processed the index between that date and now (up to 6 to 8 weeks ago).

Comment: if it was my document (or you made a small example available) I'd start from a copy of memoir to add some `\show ` or `\tracingall` around where I think the problem is to trace what it's doing but as it is, i can't help much, sorry.

Comment: (off topic, and apologies for nitpicking)  Since this theorem is attributed to three different people, the hyphens in "Heine-Borel-Lebesgue" should really be en-dashes.  Reason?  There are theorems that are attributed to two people, one of whom has a hyphenated name.  The en-dash serves to distinguish the difference.

Comment: These are the way the memoir headers are build. But you really need to boil this down to something we can test. Where is idxmark defined? Also why thst redefinition of the index command? Also what is that gobbleone doing there in the indexentry?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thnaks for catching the incorrect hyphens; I do know the distinction and that en-dashes are the appropriated separators. (I haven't proofread the index yet, just using its production to guide additional index entries as I write.)

Comment: @daleif : I now include the code showing use of `\gobbleone` and `\idxmark`. Believe me, I would dearly love to be able to boil my complex preamble specifications down and prune my hundreds of output pages of material down down to a MWE to post. I do understand that the errors seem to be originating in building headers, as an index page is being completed before being shipped out.

Comment: Otherwise, zip everything together, and email it to my obvious gmail, then I'll see if I get the same issues when I get back home tonight

Comment: Also I still do not see why you are using gobbleone

Comment: Is there any particular reason for wanting to define `\C` in that weird way? Just use a different name for the complex numbers. Anyway, we can't debug code we don't see.

Comment: @egreg: I want to use \C for complex number just as I use \R for reals, \Q for rationals, \Z for integers, and \N for natural numbers: shorter to type, easier to read as I'm writing and revising, closer to notation we use on paper or blackboard. (Note similarity of that usage to that in package mismath.sty, sec. 2.4.)

Comment: @daleif: For origin of my using `\gobbleone`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318472/change-index-see-also-and-see-format.

Comment: @murray I understand it's simpler; but if it forces you to do macro somersaults…

Comment: The problem (as I expected) is your `\idxmark` command in connection with that `\gobbleone` hackery. I'll take a a look. It is actually not related to `memoir` at all, I kan get a similar error with book + makeidx (minus the memoir index header definitions)

Comment: @daleif: Like you, I get successful result using `latexmk -norc -pdf indexerr.tex`. But I get the same error with `pdflatex indexerr`, `pdflatex indexerr`, `makeindex -s indexerr.ist indexerr`, `pdflatex indexerr` (and I'm not finding a `.latexmkrc` or `latexmkrc` in the directory of my source or in my `$HOME` (which is `~`). And how would inclusion/exclusion of the `babel` stuff change things for me?

Comment: I forgot the `.ist` file. I'm getting the same error and a similar one with book. So it does not have to do with memoir. It is something to do with then `\gobbleone` is reset, it sees to be doing so too late or something when it comes to the `\markboth`

Comment: @daleif: Do you get the error if you comment-out the `fontenc` and `babel` lines? If not and the trouble is caused by `\gobbleone`, why would `babel` cause the error, but without the `babel` code no error?

Comment: I think I got it working. Add `\let\gobbleone\relax` to the `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` lines as well. It is strange, because it still needs the one in the `\idxmark` definition as well.

Comment: What the FÅK, there seems to be something with/without babel. (not 100% confirmed yet)

Comment: If you mean to use `\gobbleone\relax\sffamily\bfseries\leftmark` and similary for `\rightmark` (on both evenhead and oddhead for index, then the headers on the index pages after the first become simply: INDEX      INDEX    INDEX (with the starting & ending entries now misssing from the left and right sides of the headers. (Or did I unintenionally omit something from my MWE preamble?)

Comment: Remember the `\let`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to help (`\let\gobbleone\relax` added four times). It is related to using `babel` as `babel` redefines `\markboth`. Honestly, I do not quite understand why the `\let...` is needed in both places. For the headers it seems to be because `\gobbleone` actually survives into the header instead of just becoming nothing. But that does not explain why it is still needed in the definition of `\idxmark`

```
\makeevenhead{index}%
{\let\gobbleone\relax\sffamily\bfseries\rightmark}%
{\sffamily\bfseries\MakeTextUppercase{\indexname}}%
{\let\gobbleone\relax\sffamily\bfseries\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{index}%
{\let\gobbleone\relax\sffamily\bfseries\rightmark}%
{\sffamily\bfseries\MakeTextUppercase{\indexname}}%
{\let\gobbleone\relax\sffamily\bfseries\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{index}{}{\sffamily\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{index}{}{\sffamily\thepage}{}
```

BTW: makeindex does not like this one: `\indexsee{nothing!nada}{nothing!nil}` see the `.ilg` file.

---

Too long for a comment. This is a much shorter MWE (the error is similar to that of `memoir`, this is just to show that this is not `memoir` specific)

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[english]{babel} % dies if babel is used
\newcommand\gobbleone[1]{}
\newcommand{\idxmark}[1]{{\let\gobbleone\relax\markboth{\sffamily\bfseries#1}{\sffamily\bfseries#1}}#1}
\begin{document}
\idxmark{thing\gobbleone }, 
\end{document}
```

As long as `babel` is not running, it works as expected. `babel` redefines `\markboth` and this its arguments no longer works as "normal".

Comment: As to `\indexsee{nothing!nada}{nothing!nil}`, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502427/get-see-index-cross-references-with-subitems.

Comment: @murray I don't think it makes any sense to have sublevels in the see part

Comment: Right, something like `\indexsee{nothing!nada}{nothing!nil}` is likely useless; but something like `\indexsee{nothing!nada}{nothing}` referring to a top-level item from another items' subentry would be useful -- and suffice for the likely-useless form.

Comment: @murray and that ought to work without makeindex complaining