# Package {embrac} seems not to work with math mode in TexLive 2020 on Windows

Tags: embrac

This MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{embrac}

\begin{document}
\textit{some $f(x)$ function}
\end{document}
```

gives me the output below on my two local PCs even after I reinstalled TexLive2020/TexStudio from the scratch on them (Windows 10 user). As we can see it prints some em distances instead of brackets while the package is supposed to print brackets in non-italics inside `\textit{}` and similar environments.

[image]

While same code seems working fine in overleaf.com documents:

[image]

I know it is a bit weird to ask people online about what's wrong with my local PCs but maybe somebody knows/can advice/can guess something or check MWE on their windows texlive installations.

So what might be wrong there with math mode and package `embrac` on my installation ? iirc`embrac` shouldn't even touch math mode which makes this issue even weirder.

Edit adressing @campa comment: with `\listfiles` enabled log file shows this:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  embrac.sty    2019/12/31 v0.9 Upright Brackets in Emphasized Text
   expl3.sty    2020-08-07 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2020-08-07 L3 backend support: PDF mode
  xparse.sty    2020-05-15 L3 Experimental document command parser
xparse-generic.tex
l3keys2e.sty    2020-05-15 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
 ***********
```

Comment: I can confirm the issue. Just for completeness please add `\listfiles` in your preamble and post the output.

Comment: @campa edited the question with the output from `\listfiles`

Comment: You should contact the package author, it was broken with the update at the end of 2019. It fails also on Overleaf in new projects (which use texlive 2020) It also fails in a fully updated texlive 2019, but if you use a texlive 2019 project on overleaf you do get the previous version and it works as overleaf is using an early texlive 2019 release.

Comment: The last `embrac` version is 2019/12/31, but the LaTeX kernel changed the handling of nested emphasis in the spring 2020 release. I assume something there went wrong. I'm not proficient in `expl3` so I have no idea. Clemens is a member of the site and will probably spot this question, otherwise you could open an issue at https://github.com/cgnieder/embrac/issues

Comment: @campa ah.  yes.  I'd better divert the blame then...

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554746/2388

Comment: I added now an issue at embrac: https://github.com/cgnieder/embrac/issues/13

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, I guess for now I can use redefinition from the issue ! Hopefully it gets fixed soon though.

Comment: The bug should've been fixed; the updated version should be available soon (it might take a while before the distributions sweep CTAN fur updates).