# How to change the text of 'see' and 'seealso'

Tags: lyx, indexing, hebrew, makeindex

I'm Hebrew user and I'm want to change the title of `see` and `see also` at the index (output of course) to Hebrew words:

- see = ראו
- see also = ראו גם

I look here:
[Change index "see also" and "see" format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318472/change-index-see-also-and-see-format)
but I didn't understand how to do this, can you help me please?

P.S. I'm using LyX if it's matters.

Thank you!!

Comment: I cannot test it now, but you should go do Documents > Settings ... > LaTeX preamble and add the lines with `\newcommand ...`, then insert the text with the index boxes (Insert>Index Entry ***and*** Insert>List>Index list) to reproduce the example and check in `View > Code Preview Pane` that code structure is almost the same to that of the linked page (specially that essentials commands as  `\printindex` are already there there) and then just test the code with Ctrl+R.

Comment: Thank you @Fran, but how can I change the `seelaso` command? I didn't understand it from you comment.... :)

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the right  to test in hebrew, But I guess that you only need a clean preamble and add *at the end of index entries* a ERT boxes (Ctrl+L) with `|see{whatewer}`  or `|seealso{whatewer}`  inside *and* configure correctly the default document language of the document, so  in german "see also" will be automaticatlly  changed to "siehe auch" and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea of Hebrew, so with non-sense words:

> [image: mwe]

This is the  LaTeX code generated with LyX (after some cleaning of non-essential parts) to produce this:

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}
חחח\index{חחח|see{םםם}} משפטית הספרות אווירונאוטיקה את, שער דת טיפול
עיצוב, ב לשון ובמתן ולחבר רבה. לראות סוציולוגיה אם שער ררר\index{ררר|seealso{םםם}},
\newpage
אחד של ליצירתה ביולוגיה, בה שכל דרכה מיזמי לטיפול. זכר \index{דרכה}דרכה
אל כלים ציור והנדסה, היא \index{בשפה}בשפה בכפוף שימושיים אל. להפוך בקרבת גם קרן.
על בקר תרבות פיסול, את שפות שנורו אתה. שתפו העזרה או עוד, שמו העיר
\newpage
םםם\index{םםם}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

> **Note**: the above code with right to left text seems that is not correctly displayed in my browser, but it should be OK when pasted to any good LaTeX editor as texworks.

And this is how  a index entry with a "see also" should look in LyX:

[image: mwe]

To produce the above code you in  <kbd>Documents</kbd><kbd>Setting...</kbd><kbd>Language</kbd> select `Hebrew` and check that <kbd>Language package</kbd> is set to `default` (now that should load the `polyglossia` package). Then in <kbd>Documents</kbd><kbd>Setting...</kbd><kbd>Fonts</kbd> check `Use non-TeX fonts(via XeTeX/LuaTeX)` and use a font with hebrew glyphs as `Linux Libertine O`.

Then write the text and index entries, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to produce the evil red text (ERT) boxes and finally <kbd>Insert</kbd><kbd>List</kbd><kbd>Index List</kbd>.

Ready. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to check it. If there are problems, export the file or check the Code Preview Pane and compare your code with the above MWE.

Answer (score 1):

The example in your link is much more complicated than you need.

All you need to do is redefine the macros `\seename` and `\alsoname` to the text you want.

If you put the following in the preamble to your document, it will change "see" and "see also" to upper case in the index. Replace them with whatever you need to get the Hebrew text strings you want.

```
\renewcommand*{\seename}{SEE}
\renewcommand*{\alsoname}{SEE ALSO}
```

(I can't give exact instructions because I don't know how you are compiling the whole document, and I don't know what the format of a Hebrew index looks like using right-to-left text.)

Comment: That will not work usually in Lyx because babel or polyglossia packages. Probably is much better just set correctly the document language.

Comment: @Fran wouldn't this work with some `\addto\captionshebrew{...}` things?

Comment: @jfbu No idea, my  experience  with hebrew in LaTeX is $log_e(0)+log_e(0)$, but I think that this approach is not needed really in this case. I have uploaded an answer with other approach.

Comment: Babel simply defines `\seename` and `\alsoname` as translations of "see" and "see also" in the selected language. I presume polyglossia does the same. But we don't know how  the OP is running TeX, except "using Lyx" - which I know nothing about.

Comment: @alephzero The main point is: If B/P translations are correct, why the hell change them? But moreover, in LyX, B/P  will be loaded *after* your redefinitions, making it useless, unless you know how not use B/A in LyX menus and then load it manually in LaTeX preamble (not for novices). Strictly speaking, use LyX do not imply TeX, but *de facto* is a quasi WYSIWYG LaTeX editor. My guess was that he used and non-TeX font, and therefore xelatex and  polyglossia because hebrew with pdflatex is troublesome.